# Extracting data with Scrapy which loops subpages

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, scrapy

There is a page on my website that contains a list of staff members. Each staff member name links to their own individual pages.

I want to output a csv file that has lists each staff member's name and title, so the spider will need to loop through each of the links on the stafflist page, pulling the names and titles.

So far, this code words only to pull out the very last name and title on the list. The problem I'm having is making it go through each person's page to get a complete list.

How do I go about making this loop work?

```
class scrapeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "scrape"
allowed_domains = ["example.com", "example.co.uk"]
start_urls = [
    'http://example.com/stafflist/',
]

def parse(self, response):
    for href in response.xpath('//div[contains(concat(" ",normalize-space(@class)," "), "span8")]//a/@href'):
        url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_SCRAPE)


def parse_SCRAPE(self, response):
    items = []
    for sel in response.xpath('//div[contains(concat(" ",normalize-space(@class)," "), "span9")]'):
        item = scrapeItem()
        item['name'] = sel.xpath('h1/text()').extract()
        item['titles'] = sel.xpath('h2/text()').extract()
        print item['name'], item['titles']
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  [CrawlSpider](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider). e.g.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

from myspider.items import PersonItem

from pyquery import PyQuery as pq  # PyQuery is awesome!
from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'myspider'
    allowed_domains = ['example.si']
    start_urls = ['http://example.com/stafflist/']

    rules = (
        # if you have paginator this Rule will extract links
        Rule(LinkExtractor(
             restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="paging"]//a[last()]')),
             follow=True),
        # restrict crawler to look for links only inside restrict_xpaths
        # and then process those links with 'parse_item'
        Rule(LinkExtractor(
             restrict_xpaths=('//div[contains(concat(" ",normalize-space(@class)," "), "span8")]//a/@href')),
             callback='parse_item',
             follow=False),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        """
        process persons page
        """
        self.response = response
        self.doc = pq(self.response.body)

        i = PersonItem()
        i["name"] = self.doc("h1").text()
        i["titles"] = self.doc("h2").text()
        ...

        return i
```